# Email provider: How to preserve value in `signIn` callback between sending email and verification calls?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I want to implement role based authentication in my app.
After researching for a while I found a simple solution - to pass role to `signIn` function

```js
signIn('email', { email, role: 'user' });
```

Then I can unpack it from `req`'s `body`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
export default async function auth(req, res) {
  return NextAuth(req, res, {
    // providers, adapters, etc.
    callbacks: {
      signIn: async ({ user }) => {
        const { body: { role } } = req;

        if (role) {
          user.role = role;
        }
        return true;
      },
      session: async ({ user, session }) => {
        session.user = {...session.user, ...user };
        return session
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Or so I thought. Magic link sign in flow has two steps: sending email and confirming it.

The `role` I provide to `signIn` function is only available during the first step and saving user to `users` collection only happens after user confirms email, so when user confirms email there's no `role`.

I tried storing `role` in cookies

```js
if (role) res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'user-role=' + role + ';Max-Age=600');
```

But cookies get overriden after I confirm email and the `role` is lost.
I don't want to create additional collections and/or records in my database.

How can I preserve `role` inside `signIn` callback without storing it in a separate database collection? Maybe there's some other solution you can think of?

Comment: Toy should create user in the database in the first step. Then when the second step happens just set the flag of verified for that user to true.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski if user was created in the first step, it'd be simple, all I'd have to do is to asign a `role` property on `user` object inside of `signIn` callback. But `user` object is writen to database in the second step, when user confirms email